# PostgreSQL function optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I got some vehicle info, coming from an external provider, in a JSON column  and the idea is to relate this info with our info, so that we can map our own vehicle to this external one. We kinda evaluate the relationship with a "diff" value in order to be aware of the best and worst mappings.

The issue: The function is slow. It can take up to 2-3 seconds. 
Briefly explaining, it searches in the vehicles table (with hundred thousands of rows), retrieves many vehicles candidates (e.g. +300) and the "diff" function takes place evaluating each of those candidates (having into account attributes' weights).

I need to enhance the performance of this function and its inner ones.

At the moment I'm almost sure that optimizing the following 2 functions is more than enough:

```
-- JSON DIFF
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_diff(
l jsonb,
r jsonb)
RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
resultado real := 0.0;
peso real := 1.0;
suma_pesos real := 0.0;
atr_l text;
atr_r text;
sigma real;
diff_atr real;

arrElement1 text;

BEGIN
FOR atr_l IN 
    SELECT key FROM jsonb_each(l)
LOOP
    IF ( (SELECT "Valor" FROM config."PesosAtributos" WHERE "Clave" LIKE atr_l) > 0 ) THEN
        suma_pesos := suma_pesos + (SELECT "Valor" FROM config."PesosAtributos" WHERE "Clave" LIKE atr_l);
    ELSE
        suma_pesos := suma_pesos + 0.1;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

--RAISE NOTICE '%', suma_pesos;

IF (l IS NULL OR l = '{}' OR r IS NULL OR r = '{}')
    THEN resultado := 1.0;
        --RAISE NOTICE 'NULL or empty';
ELSE
    FOR atr_l IN 
        SELECT key FROM jsonb_each(l)
    LOOP
        IF ( (SELECT COUNT("Valor") FROM config."PesosAtributos" WHERE "Clave" LIKE atr_l) = 1 ) THEN
            peso := (SELECT "Valor" FROM config."PesosAtributos" WHERE "Clave" LIKE atr_l);
            sigma := (SELECT "Sigma" FROM config."PesosAtributos" WHERE "Clave" LIKE atr_l);                
        ELSE
            peso := 0.1;
            sigma := 0.5;
        END IF;         

        IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsonb_each(r) WHERE key = atr_l) = 0)
            THEN resultado := resultado + peso;
                --RAISE NOTICE '% doesn''t exist in right JSON. ', atr_l;
        ELSE
            IF (is_numeric(l ->> atr_l) AND is_numeric(r ->> atr_l)) THEN
                diff_atr := peso * diff_numeric((l ->> atr_l)::real, (r ->> atr_l)::real, sigma);
                --RAISE NOTICE  '%: %, %. Peso: %. Sigma: %. Diff: %.', atr_l, (l ->> atr_l), (r ->> atr_l), peso, sigma, diff_atr;
            ELSIF (l ->> atr_l LIKE '[%]') THEN
                IF (r ->> atr_l LIKE '[%]') THEN
                --RAISE NOTICE 'LEFT ARRAY AND RIGHT ARRAY';
                diff_atr := peso * 1.0;
                FOR arrElement1 IN
                    SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(l -> atr_l)
                LOOP
                    --RAISE NOTICE '%', arrElement1;
                    IF (arrElement1 IN (SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(r -> atr_l))) THEN
                        diff_atr := peso * 0;
                        EXIT;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                ELSE
                IF (r -> atr_l IN (jsonb_array_elements_text(l -> atr_l))) THEN
                    diff_atr := peso * 0;
                ELSE 
                    diff_atr := peso * 1.0;
                END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSIF (r ->> atr_l LIKE '[%]') THEN

                IF (l -> atr_l IN (jsonb_array_elements_text(r -> atr_l))) THEN
                diff_atr := peso * 0;
                ELSE 
                diff_atr := peso * 1.0;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                diff_atr := peso * ( 1 - similarity(l ->> atr_l, r ->> atr_l)::real );  
                --RAISE NOTICE  '%: %, %. Peso: %. Diff: %.', atr_l, (l ->> atr_l), (r ->> atr_l), peso, diff_atr;      
            END IF;

            resultado := resultado + diff_atr;              
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END IF;
--RAISE NOTICE 'RESULTADO FINAL: %. SUMA PESOS: %', resultado, suma_pesos;
RETURN resultado / suma_pesos;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.json_diff(jsonb, jsonb)
OWNER TO postgres;


-- SEARCH FOR VEHICLES
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_similar_versions_with_base_entity(
tipo integer,
id integer,
top integer)
RETURNS TABLE("Diff" real, "Id" integer, "CreatedAt" bigint, "ModifiedAt" bigint, "IdVersionVehiculo" integer, "IdVersionVehiculoProveedor" integer, "Codigo" text) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
marca text;
modelo text;
anyo_ini int;
anyo_fin int;
anyo_fabr int;
anyo_matr int;
modelo_similar text;

BEGIN
SELECT vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'Marca',
vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'Modelo',
vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'AnyoInicio',
vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'AnyoFin',
vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'AnyoFabricacion',
vvp."DatosSideoJson" ->> 'AnyoMatriculacion'
INTO marca, modelo, anyo_ini, anyo_fin, anyo_fabr, anyo_matr
FROM public."VersionesVehiculoProveedor" AS vvp WHERE vvp."Id" = id;

IF (anyo_fin IS NULL) THEN anyo_fin = 0; END IF;
IF (top = -1) THEN top = NULL; END IF;

SELECT get_similar_model_group(marca, modelo) INTO modelo_similar;

IF modelo_similar IS NOT NULL THEN

    DELETE FROM public."VinsToVersionVehiculo" WHERE public."VinsToVersionVehiculo"."IdVersionVehiculoProveedor" = id;

    INSERT INTO public."VinsToVersionVehiculo" (
    "Diff",
    "IdVersionVehiculoProveedor",
    "IdVersionVehiculo",
    "CreatedAt",
    "ModifiedAt"
    )
    SELECT json_diff((SELECT vvp."DatosSideoJson" FROM public."VersionesVehiculoProveedor" AS vvp WHERE vvp."Id" = id ), j2.valores2),
    id,
    j2."IdVersion",
    0::bigint,
    0::bigint
    FROM (
    SELECT versiones."ValoresAtributosJSONB" AS valores2, versiones."Id" AS "IdVersion", marcas."Nombre" AS "Marca", modelos."Nombre" AS "Modelo", 
        modelos."Grupo" AS "Grupo", modelos."Subgrupo" AS "Subgrupo", versiones."AnyoInicio" AS "AnyoInicio", versiones."AnyoFin" AS "AnyoFin",
        mapeos."Codigo" AS "Codigo"
    FROM public."VersionesVehiculo" AS versiones
    INNER JOIN public."MapeosVersionVehiculoProveedor" AS mapeos ON versiones."Id" = mapeos."IdVersionVehiculo"
    INNER JOIN public."Modelos" AS modelos ON versiones."IdModelo" = modelos."Id"
    INNER JOIN public."Marcas" AS marcas ON modelos."IdMarca" = marcas."Id"
    INNER JOIN public."TiposVehiculo" AS tipos ON marcas."IdTipoVehiculo" = tipos."Id"
    WHERE modelos."Grupo" LIKE modelo_similar -- (modelos."AnyoInicio" <= anyo AND (modelos."AnyoFin" = 0 OR anyo <= modelos."AnyoFin"))
        AND (
            (anyo_fabr IS NOT NULL AND anyo_fabr > 0 AND year_is_in_range(anyo_fabr, modelos."AnyoInicio", modelos."AnyoFin") > 0.2)
            OR (anyo_matr IS NOT NULL AND anyo_matr > 0 AND year_is_in_range(anyo_matr, modelos."AnyoInicio", modelos."AnyoFin") > 0.2)
            OR (compare_years_interval(modelos."AnyoInicio", modelos."AnyoFin", anyo_ini, anyo_fin, 2)) 
        )
        AND versiones."ValoresAtributosJSONB" IS NOT NULL       
    ) AS j2
    ORDER BY "Diff"
    LIMIT top;
END IF;

END

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.generate_similar_versions_with_base_entity(integer, integer, integer)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Execution plan for the heavy function json_diff:

```
[
{
"Execution Time": 1004.942,
"Planning Time": 2.85,
"Plan": {
  "Inner Unique": false,
  "Startup Cost": 2.88,
  "Actual Rows": 305,
  "Plans": [
    {
      "Filter": "(\"Id\" = 6008)",
      "Startup Cost": 0,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Relation Name": "VersionesVehiculoProveedor",
      "Alias": "vvp",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Total Time": 0.008,
      "Parent Relationship": "InitPlan",
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.006,
      "Plan Width": 341,
      "Subplan Name": "InitPlan 1 (returns $0)",
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Rows Removed by Filter": 2,
      "Total Cost": 2.04
    },
    {
      "Inner Unique": false,
      "Startup Cost": 0.42,
      "Actual Rows": 298,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Inner Unique": true,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Join Filter": "(marcas.\"IdTipoVehiculo\" = tipos.\"Id\")",
          "Actual Rows": 3,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Inner Unique": false,
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Join Filter": "(modelos.\"IdMarca\" = marcas.\"Id\")",
              "Actual Rows": 3,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Actual Rows": 77,
                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                  "Plan Rows": 77,
                  "Relation Name": "Marcas",
                  "Alias": "marcas",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Actual Total Time": 0.024,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.018,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Total Cost": 1.77
                },
                {
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Actual Rows": 3,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Filter": "((\"Grupo\" ~~ 'Fiesta'::text) AND compare_years_interval(\"AnyoInicio\", \"AnyoFin\", 2003, 2008, 2))",
                      "Startup Cost": 0,
                      "Actual Rows": 3,
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Plan Rows": 3,
                      "Relation Name": "Modelos",
                      "Alias": "modelos",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Actual Total Time": 0.348,
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Actual Startup Time": 0.141,
                      "Plan Width": 8,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Rows Removed by Filter": 2505,
                      "Total Cost": 698.35
                    }
                  ],
                  "Node Type": "Materialize",
                  "Plan Rows": 3,
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Actual Total Time": 0.005,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.002,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Actual Loops": 77,
                  "Total Cost": 698.37
                }
              ],
              "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
              "Plan Rows": 3,
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 228,
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Total Time": 0.437,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.392,
              "Plan Width": 8,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Total Cost": 703.59
            },
            {
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Actual Rows": 1,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Actual Rows": 1,
                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                  "Plan Rows": 2,
                  "Relation Name": "TiposVehiculo",
                  "Alias": "tipos",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Actual Total Time": 0.006,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.006,
                  "Plan Width": 4,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Total Cost": 1.02
                }
              ],
              "Node Type": "Materialize",
              "Plan Rows": 2,
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Total Time": 0.003,
              "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.003,
              "Plan Width": 4,
              "Actual Loops": 3,
              "Total Cost": 1.03
            }
          ],
          "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
          "Plan Rows": 3,
          "Join Type": "Inner",
          "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 0,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Total Time": 0.452,
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.402,
          "Plan Width": 4,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Total Cost": 704.69
        },
        {
          "Filter": "(\"ValoresAtributosJSONB\" IS NOT NULL)",
          "Startup Cost": 0.42,
          "Scan Direction": "Forward",
          "Plan Width": 598,
          "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
          "Actual Rows": 99,
          "Node Type": "Index Scan",
          "Index Cond": "(\"IdModelo\" = modelos.\"Id\")",
          "Plan Rows": 63,
          "Relation Name": "VersionesVehiculo",
          "Alias": "versiones",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Total Time": 0.344,
          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.026,
          "Total Cost": 9.34,
          "Actual Loops": 3,
          "Rows Removed by Filter": 0,
          "Index Name": "\"IX_VersionesVehiculo_IdModelo\""
        }
      ],
      "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
      "Plan Rows": 169,
      "Join Type": "Inner",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Total Time": 1.646,
      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.431,
      "Plan Width": 594,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Total Cost": 734.61
    },
    {
      "Startup Cost": 0.42,
      "Scan Direction": "Forward",
      "Plan Width": 19,
      "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Node Type": "Index Scan",
      "Index Cond": "(\"IdVersionVehiculo\" = versiones.\"Id\")",
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Relation Name": "MapeosVersionVehiculoProveedor",
      "Alias": "mapeos",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Total Time": 0.012,
      "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.01,
      "Total Cost": 0.45,
      "Actual Loops": 298,
      "Index Name": "\"IX_MapeosVersionVehiculoProveedor_IdVersionVehiculo\""
    }
  ],
  "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
  "Plan Rows": 169,
  "Join Type": "Inner",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Actual Total Time": 1004.734,
  "Actual Startup Time": 4.083,
  "Plan Width": 31,
  "Actual Loops": 1,
  "Total Cost": 856.96
},
"Triggers": []
}
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: please show SQL queries with execution plan instead of functions.

Comment: @VaoTsun I added the execution plan for json_diff function, which is the one adding most of the global overhead (80-90%).

Comment: you seem to use Seq scans on Modulos and Marcas - consider creating indexes?..

Comment: Could you help me please to identify the right columns in which apply those indexes?

Answer (score 0):

from you plan I see SeqScan on two tables:

```
INNER JOIN public."Modelos" AS modelos ON versiones."IdModelo" = modelos."Id"
INNER JOIN public."Marcas" AS marcas ON modelos."IdMarca" = marcas."Id"
```

I assume

```
create index on public."Modelos"("Id")
create index on public."Marcas"("Id")
```

might fasten the execution

Comment: Thank you Vao, but after the creation of those indexes and some other it still shows the seq. scans. Any idea?